# Suggestions on how I can depict numerous cell towers with different ranges?

Tags: attribute-table, buffer, proximity, qgis-2.18, qgis-variable

I am trying to make buffers dependent on cell tower ranges. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to insert distance buffers of various that are dependent on attribute values in one layer?

I am using QGIS 2.18 on a MacBook

Am I understanding correctly: "various distance buffer" can make different buffer sizes dependant on feature values?

This is what i did:

> selected tower layer > vector > geoprocessing tools > variable
>   distance buffer > input layer: towers > distance field:
>   3499_tower_range_mi > segments: 1609.344 because value in meters is
>   about 1 mile > Run

That did not work, I got a message saying `"float() argument must be a string or a number"`

I am not sure what that means. My attribute column for the tower's ranges is `"double | Real"`

How can I change this to be an integer value?

Or does anyone have any suggestions on how I can depict numerous cell towers with different ranges?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is almost right, your error is that the segment is not to convert between unit but the number of segment the round part of buffer have (I belive it's the number by quarter of circle meaning that if you set segment to 2 you will get a buffer that is in fact an octogon, the higher the number of segment you set the closer to a true circle you get)

Also buffering will be in the unit of the CRS of your layer so if you use a projection in meters and your field for buffering in in mile you need to create a new field and fill it with converted value (this could be done with the field calculator)